# Matrix of Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the problem I've been working on:

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $B = (v_1,...,v_n)$ be a basis of $V$. Define $T \in L(V)$ as $Tv_k  = \sum_{I=1}^{k}v_i = v_1 + ... + v_k$. Find the matrix $[T]_B$.

I'm not really sure how to proceed with this problem. I think that the matrix should be triangular, as you are summing the previous elements of the basis, but I'm not sure how to proceed in constructing the matrix.

Comment: Consider first $Tv_1$. According to the definition, this equals $v_1$. Now identifying $B$ with the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}$n, this means that the matrix $T_B$ associated to $T$ acts like $T_Be_1=e_1$, so the first column of this matrix is just $e_1$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I understand that, but how would this work for actual matrix vector multiplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $n=4$, you have
\begin{align}
Tv_1&=v_1 \\
Tv_2&=v_1+v_2 \\
Tv_3&=v_1+v_2+v_3 \\
Tv_4&=v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4
\end{align}
so, by definition of associated matrix, you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The $k$-th column has the coefficients needed for expressing $Tv_k$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: How would this work if I were to multiply this matrix by, say, $v_4$?

Comment: You cannot multiply this matrix by $v_4$. You can multiply it by $e_4$, which is the element in $\mathbb{R}^n$ corresponding to $v_4$ under the coordinate isomorphism $V\to\mathbb{R}^n$ sending $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iv_i$ to $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$.

Comment: @MathLogic For what we know, the elements of $V$ might be ducks or beer mugs; it doesn't make sense to multiply an element of $V$ by this matrix.

Comment: @MathLogic This is a good thing to say.

Comment: So what does this matrix represent? Is there anything I can do with it, or is it just an abstract representation of $T$?

Comment: @MathLogic If you have $v\in V$, then you can write $v=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n$ and the multiplication $[T]_B\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\vdots\\\alpha_n\end{bmatrix}$ will give you the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\vdots\\\beta_n\end{bmatrix}$ such that $Tv=\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_nv_n$

Comment: I see, so the column is the coordinate representation with respect to $B$. Thanks for explaining.